# Change width of filename column in Org-Agenda Week view

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Let's say I have just one file in `org-agenda-files` called `short.org`. If I put items with active timestamps in `short.org`, they'll appear in the Week view just fine:

[image]

But if I have any other agenda files with longer names (i.e. `a-little-longer.org`), they'll break the agenda view's alignment:

[image]

This is undesirable behaviour. Is there any `org-*` variable that controls the width of the filename field/column in the Agenda Week view?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I'm currently trying out `org-agenda-columns`, and also tweaking the value of `org-columns-default-format-for-agenda`. Although it may be easier to get better alignment in Column View, I'd still prefer if there was a way to do it in the default view, without using `org-agenda-columns`.

**EDIT #2:**

Using column view, this is the closest I could get to displaying the same information as what's in the default view:

```
(setq org-columns-default-format-for-agenda "%FILE %TIMESTAMP %TODO %ITEM %TAGS")
```

[image]

Several issues:

- Couldn't get column view to show just the filename; it shows the entire path instead
- Timestamp is also displayed in full date/time, rather than just showing the time (e.g. just `11:00-12:00`)
- No space left to display the item itself

For these reasons, finding a way to change just **one** aspect of the default view (the filename field width) would be the most preferable.

Comment: The relevant variable is `org-agenda-prefix-format`. You should read its doc string (`C-h v org-agenda-prefix-format`) carefully. You probably will need to modify the `agenda` part of its value and you will need to modify the width of the `category` field. If you have problems, please add its current value to your question.

Comment: @NickD This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I set the width of the category field to `20` with `(agenda . " %i %-20:c%?-12t% s")`. Would you like me to post this as an answer below, with the value I set for `org-agenda-prefix-format`, or would you prefer to post this as an answer yourself for me to accept? (still getting the hang of SE ettiquette :-P)

Comment: Thanks for asking! I wrote it up as a comment, because I don't have time to write a proper anaswr ATM. So please go ahead and provide an answer. if there are any problems with it, it can always be edited to fix them. And I (or somebody else) can add additional answers if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @NickD's suggestion, tweaking the `agenda` part of `org-agenda-prefix-format` did the job.

```
(setq org-agenda-prefix-format
 '((agenda . " %i %-20:c%?-12t% s") ;; '%-20' sets 20 char field width
   (todo   . " %i %-12:c")
   (tags   . " %i %-12:c")
   (search . " %i %-12:c")))
```